# Access Google Drive synced files while the Google Drive app is closed?

Tags: network, crash, google

So the Google Drive app for macOS is great, but I find it often crashes randomly. The only fix for me is to restart the app, which takes quite a while. I have several large synced folders for offline access, and when the app is closed, it dismounts the Google Drive folder.

Is there a way to access the files that Google Drive has downloaded for offline access without opening the app?

Comment: Do you specifically want to find a solution for this through the MacOS app? There is a way to do what you are asking using a web browser like Google Chrome, but I'm not sure if that's the solution you desire.

Comment: Hi @mpp, I was hoping to figure out where on the disk the downloaded files are stored so I can use Finder to access them. I assume, however, they're unreadable by Finder, annoyingly...?

Comment: I understand your question now, your wording was a bit confusing to me at first. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797114/google-drive-offline-document-file-location) talks about where the files are stored if you are using Google Drive within the Google Chrome browser. You are asking about the macOS Drive app, so the answer is potentially much different. I would assume that the Google Drive app simply makes a copy of your files and stores it in `Desktop` folder or something but you said that you weren't able to find these files in Finder. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for that thread, mpp!
I can't find any of the google drive in any area of Finder - basically it appears that when the app is running, there is some kind of volume that appears, attached to a server "smb://127.0.0.1/Google Drive". That contains the files. But when the app is not running, that volume seems to be ejected and I cannot access the files contained within.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question or the Drive app is hiding the files for some reason. I haven't specifically used the Drive app but used similar apps and the offline file is usually downloaded to a pre-determined folder, like "Downloads". I found a few articles/docs, see if any fix your problem: [Access Drive files offline (2nd solution)](https://tinyurl.com/bdzktyas) [Find/access offline Drive files](https://tinyurl.com/5yyj9rys) [Drive Desktop Setup](https://tinyurl.com/y4x2twju).

Comment: Also, try checking this directory if you haven't already `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage` in a file like `https_drive.google.com_0.localstorage`